# emacsclient and EAF, at the same time

Tags: emacsclient

EAF (Emacs Application Framework) is not compatible with emacsclient, it says on the web page.

, but I don't understand why;)

I can't find a reasonable explanation why these two can't be enabled at the same time.

Any idea?;)

Comment: What is the purpose of the winking smileys in this question? ;)

Comment: "Why" questions are posed directly to authors. https://github.com/emacs-eaf/emacs-application-framework/issues